# Python -- subprocess popen and call same error -- none type not iterable?

Tags: python, subprocess, ping, typeerror, popen

I was using os.system for shell commands until I discovered it's deprecated.  So I am trying to switch to using subprocess.  Here are my uses:

```
command = genConfig.MODETECT_SWITCH_COMMAND.append(state)
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

MODETECT_SWITCH_COMMAND = ["zmpkg.pl"]

and some regular pings:

```
command = genConfig.PING_COMMAND.append(host)
response = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
if "unreachable" in response or "timed out" in response:
    response = False
else:
    response = True
    break
```

PING_COMMAND = ["ping", "-c 1 -W 1"]

Everywhere I do these things, I get this error:

```
...tracebacks...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1198, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

And I can't figure out why.  I've rechecked my use of subprocess.popen multiple places and it seems to be correct.  What might I be doing incorrectly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this:

```
MODETECT_SWITCH_COMMAND = ["zmpkg.pl"]
```

And when you do this:

```
command = genConfig.MODETECT_SWITCH_COMMAND.append(state)
```

You are assigning to `command` the output of a `list.append` call, which operates in place and returns `None`.

That is, it looks like you are assigning `command = None`.

`subprocess` module is confused because it expects the first positional argument to be an iterable, not `None`.

Comment: Rookie mistake -- thanks.  I have got to remember that .append changes the list in place, I always mix-up which command do things in-place and which give you a copy.